# mv .. with path: Where does my file go?

Tags: mv, working-directory

I have been using *nix systems for a while now, and I was surprised to see this situation in which `mv` misplaces or deletes my file. For example, I had a file `foo.txt` in the directory called `previousVersions`, and when I was in that directory's parent directory, I issued the command

```
mv previousVersions/foo.txt ..
```

expecting it to move `foo.txt` up to my working directory. Instead, `foo.txt` is in neither the original directory nor my working directory. Why did this happen and where did my file go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mv previousVersions/foo.txt ..` will move the file `foo.txt` to the directory above your working directory. To have the file be moved to your working directory, replace `..` with `.`:

`mv previousVersions/foo.txt .`

With the file presently in the parent directory of your current working directory, you can move it to your current working directory with this command:

`mv ../foo.txt .`

Comment: Oh that makes sense now that I think about it. . and .. represent the working directory not the directory referenced.

Answer (score 2):

The file is not removed, it lies waiting for you in the parent directory of your (then) current working directory.

The `..` in the target of `mv` is relative to *your current* working directory, not to that of the source file.